# How to get third level of data in JSON response?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to get Flickr data from API:

I have used following API `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=c87d0837c5bea1ac860102de95eee254&user_id=134029050%40N05&page=1&per_page=10&format=rest`

My code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var flickerAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=c87d0837c5bea1ac860102de95eee254&user_id=134029050%40N05&page=1&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
        $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
            tags: "mount rainier",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        })
.done(function (data) {
    // debugger;
    $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function (i, item) {
        alert(data.photosets.photoset[i].title);

        var span = $('<span />').html(item[i]["title"]);
        $("#images").append(span);


    });
});
    })();
</script>
```

I want to get title of "photoset" element, i am able to get properties of "photoset", but i don't know how to fetch data inside "photoset".

Please help me.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title is actually stored in _content inside of the title object.  So you need to use:

```
data.photosets.photoset[i].title._content
```

Or inside of your loop, it would just be:

```
item.title._content
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dho9xbt8/

Comment: JSON structure is not posted in question.

Comment: The question posted all of the code needed.  It's a simple get request, all anyone had to do was go to the URL in the get request and look at the JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

You just simply need to use : **item.title._content** to get the third level of json for the **title**

Please check my code to get result

```js
(function () {
        var flickerAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=c87d0837c5bea1ac860102de95eee254&user_id=134029050%40N05&page=1&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
        $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
            tags: "mount rainier",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        })
.done(function (data) {
    // debugger;
    $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function (i, item) {
        //console.log(data.photosets.photoset[i].title._content);
        alert(item.title._content);
        var span = $('<span />').html(item.title._content);
        $("#images").append(span);


    });
});
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @BenFried No, i have really no idea what you have answer. because i am working on snippet at that time. and debugging on it...